# In DDD with Entity Framework where should the Context Interface live?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm using Entity Framework in my DDD Application where I have Domain, Infra and UI Layers.

My Context Interface is here:

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    DbEntityEntry Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;

    void SaveChanges();
}
```

My Context Interface actually lives in the Domain Layer.

How are you seeing, my context has a dependency of Entity Framework because my base repository and my entire app use that.

Where should I put this Interface? Move that to Infra? I want to isolate my Domain of any technologies.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the interface to ifra layer. Also you should ensure that this interface or any type implementing the interface is not directly used in any other layer because once you access `DbSet` or `DbEntityEntry` elsewhere you have a dependency.

Comment: Why move the Interface to Infra Layer? Is there a DDD explanation Or some other motive?

Comment: The interface is dependent on Entity framework and you mentioned that you want to isolate domain from any technology. Isolate = not have dependency on the technology.

Comment: Yes features like ORM context / sessions, database connections etc. belongs to infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should forget about directly using the IDbContext inteface. A better solution, IMHO, would be to define Repository interfaces on you domain, without any reference to the Entity Framework and, in the infrastructure layer, you would define the implementations for that repository.

Any query to models would be done through the repositories which, in turn, returns a model or an IEnumrable of models.